# Allocators For Nested Container

Tags: c++, nested, allocator

Following a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3dz-AKOVL8) about allocators at *CppCon*, I came across the [following piece of code](https://ideone.com/RcEycq):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace {

template <typename T>
class MyAllocator {
 public:
  using value_type = T;

  MyAllocator(std::string iType) : _type(std::move(iType)) {}

  T* allocate(const std::size_t iNo) { return new T[iNo]; }
  void deallocate(T* iPtr, const std::size_t) { delete[] iPtr; }

  constexpr bool operator!=(const MyAllocator& oth) const {
    return _type != oth._type;
  }

  const std::string& getType() const noexcept { return _type; }

 private:
  std::string _type;
};

using MyString =
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>>;

}  // anonymous namespace

int main(int, char**) {
  ::MyString str1(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr1"));
  ::MyString str2(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr2"));
  ::MyString str3(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr3"));

  std::vector<::MyString> aVector;
  aVector.reserve(1024);

  aVector.push_back(str1);
  aVector.push_back(str2);

    std::cout << "[0]: " << aVector[0].get_allocator().getType() << "\n"
              << "[1]: " << aVector[1].get_allocator().getType() << "\n";


  aVector.insert(aVector.begin(), str3);

  const auto& type0 = aVector[0].get_allocator().getType();
  const auto& type1 = aVector[1].get_allocator().getType();
  const auto& type2 = aVector[2].get_allocator().getType();

  std::cout << "[0]: " << type0 << "\n"
            << "[1]: " << type1 << "\n"
            << "[2]: " << type2 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I guess the general topic here is about "*allocators in nested containers*". Although functionally speaking, I get the issue, I cannot understand what happened in the code.

In the code, we have a custom *allocator* which, essentially, behaves like the default allocator except it stores a kind of data internally.

I build *three* different strings with three *different* instances of the same allocator:

```
using MyString = 
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>>;

::MyString str1(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr1"));
::MyString str2(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr2"));
::MyString str3(::MyAllocator<char>("ForStr3"));
```

Now I have a simple `std::vector<MyString>`:

```
std::vector<::MyString> aVector;
aVector.reserve(1024);
```

I reserved the space in order to avoid *reallocation*.

Now I push the first two strings:

```
aVector.push_back(str1);
aVector.push_back(str2);

std::cout << "[0]: " << aVector[0].get_allocator().getType() << "\n"
          << "[1]: " << aVector[1].get_allocator().getType() << "\n";

// As expected, it prints:
//       [0]: ForStr1
//       [1]: ForStr2
```

The result of the print is what I expect. I assume the allocator is owned by the `std::string` container.

*However* if I force some copy/movements (rearrangement) with an:

```
aVector.insert(aVector.begin(), str3);

// Now we have vector be like:
//  [str3:ForStr3]    [str1:ForStr1]    [str2:ForStr2]
```

Then, the allocators associated with the strings inside the vector seem to be corrupted:

```
const auto& type0 = aVector[0].get_allocator().getType();
const auto& type1 = aVector[1].get_allocator().getType();
const auto& type2 = aVector[2].get_allocator().getType();

std::cout << "[0]: " << type0 << "\n"
          << "[1]: " << type1 << "\n"
          << "[2]: " << type2 << "\n";
```

It prints:

```
[0]: ForStr1
[1]: ForStr2
[2]: ForStr2
```

I expect:

```
[0]: ForStr3
[1]: ForStr1
[2]: ForStr2
```

---

Why this behaviour? Is there an *UB* that I missed?
The allocator associated with a `std::string` is part of the object itself, isn't?

Comment: This is affected by [allocator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) which decides if the allocator should be copied and moved with the string (or not).

Comment: what compiler and settings did you use? I tried it with gcc 7.3.0 `g++ org.cc  && ./a.out` and for the last part I got `ForStr2` three times. With `g++ org.cc -O && ./a.out` I get `ForStr1`, empty, `ForStr2`. If i remove the call to `vector::reserve` and use `g++ org.cc -O` i get the expected answer. I do not know enough about the standard or allocators to say if it is UB, but it is unexpected. I will continue digging.